# Let any visitors delete a post if they know Id nr & password?

Tags: custom-field, front-end, wp-delete-post

I've got only one function left that I need to solve (if it's solvable).

I've got a frontend post system for unregistered users.
But there are no way for the users to delete a post if they later want.

So I was thinking, if I in my form (where they create their post), ask them to write a password in a custom field, is there then anyway to delete the post by using the post id nr and the password they provided?

.. Or is this completely impossible?

The reason I want this is because currently no front-end custom poster plugins have any preview function, and maybe the user did something wrong and they want to do another post..

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using WordPress.

You can do the following things alternatively :
**While the user is creating a post, allot them a [post_id] and [password]/[hash/key] whatever.**
**When they will comeback and try to delete ask them for the id and password/hash to delete.**

By using `get_the_ID` you can display the post id.
And hash can be created `wp_generate_password` function.
Also you have to use `add_post_meta` to save the hash.
In this example the delete form is always visible you can use additional js and css to hid this and visible on click.

### SOLUTION

```
//FUNCTION TO INSERT DELETE FORM AFTER EVERY POST.

function auto_insert_after_post($content){
    if (is_single()) {
        $content .= '
            <form action="'. esc_url( admin_url("admin-post.php") ) .'" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="aid" required>
                <input type="text" name="hash" required>
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="hash_auth">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete">
            </form>
        ';
        $content .= "value:".get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), "delete_auth_key", true );
    }
    return $content;
}

//FUNCTION TO GENERATE A POST HASH/PASSWORD DURING POST CREATION.

function generate_post_hash($id, $post){
    $hash_key = "delete_auth_key";
    $hash = wp_generate_password(10);
    add_post_meta($id, $hash_key, $hash);
}

//AUTHENTICATE AND DELETE POST

function delete_hash_auth(){
    //check if form fields are filled
    if(!empty($_POST['aid']) && !empty($_POST['hash'])){
        $aid = $_POST['aid'];
        $hash = $_POST['hash'];
        $auth_hash = get_post_meta($aid, "delete_auth_key", true);
        //check if the hash and the post id matches
        if(get_post($aid) && $auth_hash == $hash){
            //check if auth_hash matches hash
            wp_delete_post($aid);
        }
        else{
            echo "Please enter correct post id and hash!";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "Empty fields not allowed!";
    }
    
}
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_hash_auth', 'delete_hash_auth', 10);
add_action( 'admin_post_hash_auth', 'delete_hash_auth', 10 );
add_action( "publish_post", "generate_post_hash", 20, 2 );
add_filter( "the_content", "auto_insert_after_post" );
```

### IMPLEMENT USING PLUGIN

These are the steps to implement using a plugin or you can simply download this plugin I have written. Download [Frontend Delete](http://ivst.xooweb.com/frontend-del.zip)

If you downloaded the plugin.

1. Go to Dashboard > Plugin > Add New
2. Upload the downloaded zip.
3. Activate the plugin.
4. Done.

If you wanna write it the please follow the steps:

1. Create a Directory `frontend-del` in wp-content/plugins folder
2. Create `frontend-del.php` inside that folder.
3. Paste this code below.

/*
Plugin Name: frontend-del
Plugin URI: https://www.wordpress.org
Description: Enable frontend delete.
Version: 1.0
Author: Behemoth
Author URI: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/188582/behemoth
License: GPLv2 or later
*/

```
function delete_hash_auth(){
    
//check if form fields are filled
if(!empty($_POST['aid']) && !empty($_POST['hash'])){
    $aid = $_POST['aid'];
    $hash = $_POST['hash'];
    $auth_hash = get_post_meta($aid, "delete_auth_key", true);
    //check if the hash and the post id matches
    if(get_post($aid) && $auth_hash == $hash){
        //check if auth_hash matches hash
        wp_delete_post($aid);
    }
    else{
        echo "Please enter correct post id and hash!";
    }
}
else{
    echo "Empty fields not allowed!";
}

  }

add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_hash_auth', 'delete_hash_auth', 10);
add_action( 'admin_post_hash_auth', 'delete_hash_auth', 10 ); 
function generate_post_hash($id, $post){
    $hash_key = "delete_auth_key";
    $hash = wp_generate_password(10);
    add_post_meta($id, $hash_key, $hash);
}
add_action( "publish_post", "generate_post_hash", 20, 2 );
function auto_insert_after_post($content){
    if (is_single()) {
        $content .= '
            <form action="'. esc_url( admin_url("admin-post.php") ) .'" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="aid" required>
                <input type="text" name="hash" required>
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="hash_auth">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete">
            </form>
        ';
        $content .= "value:".get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), "delete_auth_key", true );
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter( "the_content", "auto_insert_after_post" );
```

4. Do not skip the above comment line. and place the whole thing inside `<?php ... ?>`.
5. Save it and go to your WordPress Dashboard > plugin and activate the `frontend del` plugin

### CONCLUSION

This is a basic solution you can customise it to fit your needs. For example you may need a ajax submission or redirect it to your desired page.
Also you can further implement this using object oriented concepts.

Comment: Hi @Behemoth thx for the information, sorry for the delay on my answer. I've been looking at it a couple of times, I'm still trying to workout where to put what.. or is all this code going into functions.php?

Comment: Yes, you can implement it in your functions.php file.

Comment: thx a lot for the help, but I'm afraid I'm too stupid to implement those, well, add them to functions.php isn't an issue, but there it stops for me, I can't Ajax or java (basics, I can change and modify things, but not create something from scratch..)

Comment: Ok, then let me implement this in plugin so that you can implement it easily.

Comment: I'm.. having problem with finding the right words, thank you..

Comment: still around? I hope you're okay in this covid19 crisis..

Comment: Really sorry for the late reply. I have updated the answer to show how to implement this in a plugin. Also you can download that file from my [link](http://ivst.xooweb.com/frontend-del.zip) Let me know if there is any problem.